# PHP function not found with require_once in html

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute a function in a file called 'function.php' into `<?php ?>` with a require_once, in HTML lines..

accueil.php (C:\wamp\www\e-commerce\MusicStore\accueil.php) :

```
<?php
require_once('http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/function.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <?php
      get_header();
      ?>
   </body>
....
</html>
```

and function.php (C:\wamp\www\e-commerce\MusicStore\templates\function.php ):

```
<?php
function get_header()
{
    echo "<header class=\"header\">
    <div class=\"banniere\">
            <a href=\"accueil.php\"><img src=\"http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/logo.png\" alt=\"banniere\"/></a>
    </div>
    </header>";
}
?>
```

I got " Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() ".

But if I put the echo outside of the function, it works.. This is only into the function It doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to resolve this? I'm trying to clear my website with adding PHP function to structure my html page.

EDIT : The double '{' is a mistake on Stackoverflow but isn't in the file.

Comment: Remove the `http://localhost/` from `require_once('http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/function.php');` do `require_once('e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/function.php');`

Comment: thanks, I tried but doesn't work so I tried this :
require_once('./templates/function.php'); and it works :)

Thank you!

Comment: require needs a path (full path would be recommended) and not a url

Comment: I was going to add that you may need to modify that a bit in order to suit the folder/path. @user225416 Glad to see it worked out.

Comment: remove the extra { in your function

Comment: something along these lines should work for you:
`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/function.php';`

Comment: @user225416 please use mamdouh alramadan's solution. Otherwise you always have to change the path, if your file moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pls try this

```
<?php
 require_once('templates/function.php');
 ?>
```

and replace function.php because it has extra`{`

```
<?php
function get_header() 
{
echo "<header class=\"header\">
<div class=\"banniere\">
        <a href=\"accueil.php\"><img src=\"http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/logo.png\" alt=\"banniere\"/></a>
</div>
</header>";
}
?>
```

Comment: require_once('./templates/function.php');

Tested 30min ago and works fine, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Function has 2 opening braces {
Here is the fixed code:

```
function get_header() {
    echo "<header class=\"header\">
    <div class=\"banniere\">
            <a href=\"accueil.php\"><img src=\"http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/logo.png\" alt=\"banniere\"/></a>
    </div>
    </header>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake while I was writing the post =)

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming folder location of your accueil.php  is same as function.php

```
<?php
 require_once('function.php');
 ?>
```

If its different then try relative path. If you can tell about locations of your both files you will get better help here.

Comment: don't make assumptions, and what if the accueil.php location changed in the future, then you need to modify the code for that??

Comment: ofcourse you do, first of all @user225416 need to understand that what path should be given.

Comment: Thanks, the location of function.php is in ./template/

Answer (score -4):

The better approach is:

```
   function get_header() {
   {
     return  "your code here";
   }
   echo get_header();
```

The function is not a very good place to echo from

Comment: how is this even relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: he told that echo outside function will print result. This is the solution.

Comment: Uh, no. It wasn't working because the path was wrong; this literally has nothing to do with OP's issue.